# How can I divide two doubles and output the quotient?

Tags: c, double, division

As part of this program I'm creating in C I have to divide a double value called 'money' by a decimal number (e.g. 0.55, 0.85, 0.90 etc.). I then want to store the value of this division and output ONLY the integer of this division and not the remainder.
For example if I did 1.30 / 0.55 then the real answer is 2.363636..
However I only want to output the 2 part of the answer and not the remainder. When I run my program however the output of this division is always 0.000000 and I cannot work out why the answer isn't correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  char candy;
  double money;
  double quant;
  scanf( "%c %lf", &candy, &money );

  switch ( candy )
  {
  case 'a' :
     quant = money / 0.55;
     if ( quant >= 1 )
        printf( "You selected Mars and have enough money to buy %1.lf bars", &quant );
     else
        printf( "You selected Mars, but, do not have enough money" );
     break;
```

For example when I enter money as 1.40 then I am expecting:
"You selected Mars and have enough money to buy 2 bars"
However the actual output is:
"You selected Mars and have enough money to buy 0.0000000 bars"

I'm quite new to C programming so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Many thanks

Comment: You very, very rarely want to use `&foo` in `printf` - use plain `quant` there instead. The answer below also shows how to get the integer out of the double, but this little thing is good to know too. You do the &thing in scanf because scanf needs to save to the variable. printf just displays it so you don't wan the &. (& means "take the address of this variable" - which scanf uses to know where to put its result.)

Comment: btw - you have stumbled upon an area that you would think would be simple but is not. Computers have enormous problems with 'exact' whole numbers, google around and you will see many things on stack overflow and elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int quant = (int)(money / 0.55);
 if ( quant >= 1 )
    printf( "You selected Mars and have enough money to buy %d bars", quant );
```

This will remove everything after the decimal point. If you want to force round up or down you need the functions floor and ceil

Comment: The (int)(...) thing is called casting the value to a new type. When you cast a double or float to an int, it keeps the integer part and discards the rest.

Comment: Thanks very much this solution seems to have worked for me apart from 1 problem, the divisions seem to work for all values except for when I enter money as 1.65. Even though I am expecting 3 to be returned I am getting 2. Is this due to the precision of the calculations? When I enter 2.20 I get 4 and 2.75 I get 5 etc.

Comment: @Sketzii yes, that's because floating point does not exactly represent 1.65 and/or 0.55 .  To be exactly accurate you need to use integer types (e.g. store the number of cents) instead.

Comment: you can force it to round up by doing quant = ceil(money/0.55)